# How prove this integral equation has a unique solution

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

**Question:**

Consider the equation 
$$3u(x)=x+(u(x))^2+\int_{0}^{1}|x-u(y)|^{1/2}dy$$

show that it has a continous solution $u$ satisfying $0\le u(x)\le 1$ for $0\le  x\le 1$

this problem From [page 376](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=DfC7AQAAQBAJ&pg=PA376&lpg=PA376&dq=Show+that+it+has+a+continuous+solution+u+satisfying&source=bl&ots=VGjxH4Cl6F&sig=U5LvrMJT4uH8SNbZOc638l2fXBg&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ei=soEpVPbHGM-A8QWjwoGQBw&ved=0CBsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Show%20that%20it%20has%20a%20continuous%20solution%20u%20satisfying&f=false) ,he says 
Hint: Krasnoselskii’s ﬁxed point theorem

My idea:

let $f(x_{1}),f(x_{2})$ is solution,then $f=f_{1}(x)-f_{2}(x)$

I
Thank you

Comment: What the "let $f(x_1),f(x_2)$ is solution" is going to mean?

Answer (score 0):

It can be written equivalently as
$$
u(x)=\frac{3}{2}-\left(\frac{9}{4}-x-\int_{0}^{1}\vert x-u(y)\rvert^{1/2}dy\right)^{1/2}=:\big({\mathcal F}(u)\big)(x)
$$
Clearly, the nonlinear functional maps the closed unit ball of $C[0,1]$ to itself, and in fact to a compact subset of it (use [Arzelà–Ascoli theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem)), and due to [Schauder Fixed Point Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_fixed_point_theorem) it has a fixed point.